# set default start date in calender mydatepicker angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, bootstrap-datepicker, ng2-datepicker

I am using mydatepicker package of angular 2.

I have to disable dates before `01-01-1995` & disable dates after `31-12-2005` means date range should between 01-01-1995 to 31-12-2005. I used `disableSince` & `disableUntil` property of the datepicker.

Dates before & after from above range are disabled; but the calendar displays the current month & year I have to start the year from January 1995 on a calendar.

If I set to default date it displays in the placeholder; but I don't want to display the date in the placeholder but set the default date January 1995.

[image: calender set to default year & month]

[image: default date set to placeholder]

Comment: What do you have tried so far

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still need to add further information for your question to become solvable.